# HTML symbol codes not working in toggle html jQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, toggle

I want to toggle `+` and `-` symbols using codes `&#43`; and `&#45;`

I tried following solutions for toggling HTML, but it doesn't seem to work for these codes. It toggles once, but won't toggle back.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/soh26n5w/1/)

**HTML**

```
<p>&#43;</p>
```

**jQuery**

```
jQuery('p').on('click', function(){
  jQuery('p').html(jQuery('p').html() === '&#45;' ? '&#43;' : '&#45;');
});
```

How can I fix this so the toggle works?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you want to use ascii codes in this case, but you could achieve your condition like :

```js
jQuery('p').on('click', function() {
  jQuery('p').html( jQuery('p').html() === '-' ? '&#43;' : '&#45;' );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>&#43;</p>
```

Or if you want to use just ascii codes, you could convert the value first then compare like :

```js
jQuery('p').on('click', function(){
  var ascii = '&#'+jQuery('p').html().charCodeAt(0)+';';
  
  jQuery('p').html(ascii === '&#45;' ? '&#43;' : '&#45;');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>&#43;</p>
```

Hope this helps.